# How to replace Special Characters/symbols in Pandas Data Frame(csv file) to NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, replace, special-characters

Hi everyone,

```
 I am new to the handling of data in pandas DataFrame could you please help me to solve the problem.

 My question is how to replace special symbols(like ?,@,#,$,&,^ and so on) with NaN.
```

For Example:
My CSV file((Ram.csv) file look like this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the column only supports Alphabets, then you can make a check for ASCII for alphabets and replace any other character whose ASCII does not match the ASCII of alphabets.You can replace the special characters with empty string using the above login and then use this to replace them with NaN.

```
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```